# How to put two pandas dataframes together, with one dataframe missing dates

Tags: python, pandas

I have historical ticker data in one dataframe, and historical dividend data in another dataframe. They look like this:

```
        Date        High        Low         Open        Close       Volume      Adj Close
0       1993-01-29  43.968750   43.750000   43.968750   43.937500   1003200.0   26.453930
1       1993-02-01  44.250000   43.968750   43.968750   44.250000   480500.0    26.642057
2       1993-02-02  44.375000   44.125000   44.218750   44.343750   201300.0    26.698507
3       1993-02-03  44.843750   44.375000   44.406250   44.812500   529400.0    26.980742
4       1993-02-04  45.093750   44.468750   44.968750   45.000000   531500.0    27.093624
... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...
6809    2020-02-13  338.119995  335.559998  335.859985  337.059998  54501900.0  337.059998
6810    2020-02-14  337.730011  336.200012  337.510010  337.600006  64582200.0  337.600006
6811    2020-02-18  337.670013  335.209991  336.510010  336.730011  57226200.0  336.730011
6812    2020-02-19  339.079987  337.480011  337.790009  338.339996  48639100.0  338.339996
6813    2020-02-20  338.640015  333.681702  337.742004  336.894989  63193703.0  336.894989
```

```
            action      value
2019-12-20  DIVIDEND    1.570
2019-09-20  DIVIDEND    1.384
2019-06-21  DIVIDEND    1.432
2019-03-15  DIVIDEND    1.233
2018-12-21  DIVIDEND    1.435
... ... ...
1994-03-18  DIVIDEND    0.271
1993-12-17  DIVIDEND    0.317
1993-09-17  DIVIDEND    0.286
1993-06-18  DIVIDEND    0.318
1993-03-19  DIVIDEND    0.213
```

## I want something like this:

```
        Date        High        Low         Open        Close       Volume      Adj Close       Dividend
0       1993-01-29  43.968750   43.750000   43.968750   43.937500   1003200.0   26.453930           
1       1993-02-01  44.250000   43.968750   43.968750   44.250000   480500.0    26.642057           
2       1993-02-02  44.375000   44.125000   44.218750   44.343750   201300.0    26.698507           
3       1993-02-03  44.843750   44.375000   44.406250   44.812500   529400.0    26.980742           
4       1993-02-04  45.093750   44.468750   44.968750   45.000000   531500.0    27.093624           
... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...
6809    2020-02-13  338.119995  335.559998  335.859985  337.059998  54501900.0  337.059998          1.570
6810    2020-02-14  337.730011  336.200012  337.510010  337.600006  64582200.0  337.600006          1.570
6811    2020-02-18  337.670013  335.209991  336.510010  336.730011  57226200.0  336.730011          1.570
6812    2020-02-19  339.079987  337.480011  337.790009  338.339996  48639100.0  338.339996          1.570
6813    2020-02-20  338.640015  333.681702  337.742004  336.894989  63193703.0  336.894989          1.570
```

(I have no dividend data before 1993-03-19, but I do onward.)

Basically, I want to merge them so that the dividend column is continuous with the dates in the historical dataframe.

Comment: 1) You should always include your data as text, not pictures. 2) your expected outcome should be consistent with your sample data.

Comment: @QuangHoang - Got it! Fixed.

Comment: Look at using `pd.DataFrame.merge`

Answer (score 1):

You can join, then fill missing values and finally rename  columns.

Supose your dataframes are named `market_prices` and `dividend_data`.

You can do this:

```
import pandas as pd

# Make sure the keys share type
market_prices['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(market_prices['Date'])
dividend_data.index = pd.to_datetime(dividend_data.index)

# Join the data
prices_with_dividends = market_prices.join(
    dividend_data['value'], how='left', on='Date'
)
# Fill missing values with previous data
prices_with_dividends['value'].fillna(method='ffill', inplace=True)
# Rename column
prices_with_dividends.rename({'value': 'Dividend'}, axis=1, inplace=True)
```

That should do.

Comment: `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable` on line 3 `dividend_data['value'], how='left'` I tried `dividend_data["Date"]=pd.to_datetime(dividend_data["Date"])`

Comment: @jangles, sorry, you need to specify which key to use on the original dataframe with the option `on='Date'`. I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `df` is the data frame with historical ticker data, and `df2` is the one with dividend information.

```py
#prerequisite:
df["Date"]=pd.to_datetime(df["Date"])

df=df.set_index("Date")
df["Dividend"]=df2["value"]
df=df.reset_index()
```

Comment: This seems like it should work but every row in the new `Dividend` column is NaN for me. Plus I'm not sure that this would match and fill the dividends correctly.

Comment: Hm, it should for matching indexes - what could happen here is possibly the type differ between these 2 - i.e. one date is a ```datetime``` and the other one is the string. You can eg. start with ```df["Date"]=pd.to_datetime(df["Date"])``` (if ```df2``` has ```datetime``` index)

Comment: The dividend data came with the date as the index. I reset the index and made the dates into their own `Date` column, and tried your `dividend_data["Date"]=pd.to_datetime(df["Date"])` on both DFs but it still does the same thing. It must be a NoneType error, that the `pd.to_datetime` doesn't seem to fix.

Comment: Nope, hold on - could you share the results of ```df.index.dtype``` for both data frames (once both have ```Date``` as index)

Comment: For df: `AttributeError: 'RangeIndex' object has no attribute 'dtypes'`
For df2: `AttributeError: 'DatetimeIndex' object has no attribute 'dtypes'`

Comment: My bad - singular - it's ```df.index.dtype```

Comment: Oh my bad too, I have to put `Date` as the index, not as a column. But it is `dtype('int64')` for df and `dtype('<M8[ns]')` for df2.

Comment: Ok- you need to change ```Date``` from ticker history data - I added line for this above

Comment: Still NaN :(. `df2` is supposed to have the date column as the index as well, correct?

Comment: Well, they are supposed to be of the same type (actually for all solutions, regardless whether it's ```join```, ```merge``` or the above). So you can make them into datetime-s, or strings (```object```) just to make sure they both are of the same type.

Comment: I got it figured out here https://stackoverflow.com/a/60329377/8142044. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Interpolated from [@fjsh's answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60328326/8142044)

```
# Join the data
prices_with_dividends = features.set_index('Date').join(dividend_data.set_index('Date'))

# Fill missing values with previous data
prices_with_dividends['Value'].fillna(method='ffill', inplace=True)

# Rename column
prices_with_dividends.rename({'Value': 'Dividend'}, axis=1, inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
price_table = price_table.merge(dividend_table, left_on = 'Date', right_on ='Date',how = 'outer')
price.value = price.value.fillna('')
```

If the dates are not in the same format convert using:

```
price_table['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(price_table['Date'])
```